# I'm getting KeyError trying to scrape data from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a code for data scraping; it works well for some pages, but for some it displays:

> KeyError: 'isbn'.

Could you please guide me on how can I solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import sys
import codecs


def Soup(content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def Main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = Soup(r.content)
    scripts = soup.findAll("script", type="application/ld+json",
                           text=re.compile("data"))
    prices = [span.text for span in soup.select(
        "p.product-field.price span span") if span.text != "USD"]
    with open("AudioBook/Fiction & Literature/African American.csv", 'a', encoding="utf-8", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Title", "Writer", "Price", "IMG", "URL", "ISBN"])
        for script, price in zip(scripts, prices):
            script = json.loads(script.text)
            title = script["data"]["name"]
            author = script["data"]["author"][0]["name"]    
            img = f'https:{script["data"]["thumbnailUrl"]}'
            isbn = script["data"]["isbn"]
            url = script["data"]["url"]
            writer.writerow([title, author, price, img, url, isbn])
for x in range(1,10):
    url = ("https://www.kobo.com/ww/en/audiobooks/contemporary-1?pageNumber=" + str(x))
    print("Scrapin page " + str(x) + ".....")
    Main(url)
```

Comment: That tells you that `script["data"]` has no key `isbn`. Have you checked your HTML?

Comment: yes I checked and there is a key isbn.

Comment: My intuition is that you have at least one case without. You should decide how you want to handle those which don't have the ISBN, e.g. writing the CSV with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Since audiobooks don't have an ISBN on the listings page, you could prepare for this case with a default value, e.g.:

```
isbn = script["data"].get("isbn", "")
```

In this case, if the `"isbn"` key doesn't exist in `script["data"]`, it will fallback on the value of an empty string.

Alternatively, you could get the book ISBN from the audiobook-specific page (your `script["data"]["url"]` above), e.g.:

```
def Main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = Soup(r.content)
    scripts = soup.findAll("script", type="application/ld+json",
                           text=re.compile("data"))
    prices = [span.text for span in soup.select(
        "p.product-field.price span span") if span.text != "USD"]
    with open("AudioBook/Fiction & Literature/African American.csv", 'a', encoding="utf-8", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Title", "Writer", "Price", "IMG", "URL", "ISBN"])
        for script, price in zip(scripts, prices):
            script = json.loads(script.text)
            title = script["data"]["name"]
            author = script["data"]["author"][0]["name"]    
            img = f'https:{script["data"]["thumbnailUrl"]}'
            # NEW CODE
            url = script["data"]["url"] 
            if "isbn" in script["data"]:
                # ebook listings
                isbn = script["data"]["isbn"]
            else:
                # audiobook listings                            
                r = requests.get(url)                                               
                inner_soup = Soup(r.content)
                try:                                       
                    inner_script = json.loads(
                        inner_soup.find("script", type="application/ld+json",                           
                                        text=re.compile("workExample")).text)                           
                    isbn = inner_script["workExample"]["isbn"]
                except AttributeError:
                    isbn = ""
            # END NEW CODE
            writer.writerow([title, author, price, img, url, isbn])
```

Comment: bro it works but it only display empty field of isbn and if you check in html there is isbn available. Could you please have a look into html? please sir

Comment: I checked, the ISBN is not part of the data: view-source:https://www.kobo.com/ww/en/audiobooks/contemporary-1?pageNumber=1. ISBN is only present when you navigate to the book specific page of the site.

Comment: then how can we extract ISBN? is there any solution?

Comment: You will need to follow the URL you extract using `script["data"]["url"]`, i.e. get this page using `requests.get` and then extract the ISBN from there.

Comment: bro my code is ok for this some links like: https://www.kobo.com/ww/en/ebook/the-last-letter-from-juliet with this link my code working well but why not working for some urls

Comment: See my edit. Your code won't work on the listing pages because they don't have the ISBN data. You can navigate to the individual book pages to retrieve this.

Comment: bro love you soo much but please don't mind I'm confused where I have to put your edited code into my code. could you please fit your code into my code that will be very cleasr for me. thanks and sorry for repeating this.

Comment: thank you bro , it showing now:   text=re.compile("workExample")).text)      
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: It looks like there are a few cases where this can't be used to get ISBN, but it works in most cases. I have added a `try/except` to handle this. You could also investigate the cause yourself and see if there is another way to get the ISBN.